# Submit form only after validation of file size and file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using the following code to submit a form to upload cv. I want to check the extension and size of the file selected. And submit the form only if certain conditions are satisfied. For now the form display alert messages. But user can still submit the form. Below is the code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="qual" class="form-horizontal" action="updater.php"  method="post">
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="act">Upload CV</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input required type="file" name="cv" id="cv" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="help-block">File size must be less than 2MB. <br>Allowed file types are pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, rtf, txt</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn"></label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="btn2" name="btn2" class="btn btn-success">Update CV</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>

    $("#cv").change( function(submitEvent) {
       var fileSize = this.files[0];
       var sizeInMb = (fileSize.size/1024)/1024;
       var sizeLimit= 2;
       if (sizeInMb > sizeLimit) {
                alert('File size must be less than 2MB');
       }
       else 
       {
                submitEvent.preventDefault();
       }

       var filename = $("#cv").val();
       var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
       if (extension == filename) {
           extension = '';
       } else {
           extension = extension.toLowerCase();
       }
       switch (extension) {
        case 'pdf':
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx':
        case 'ppt':
        case 'pptx':
        case 'rtf':
        case 'txt':
        $("#qual").submit(function(e){
            $("#qual").unbind('submit').submit()
        });
        break;

        default:
            alert('Inavlid file type')
            submitEvent.preventDefault();
       }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless your question is specifically about this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the checks when the file is changed but not when the form is submitted. For that reason the user can still submit the form even if the file doesn't fulfill the requirements.

If you execute that same code when the form is submitted, it works fine. To achieve that:

- Change `$("#cv").change()` for `$("#qual").submit()`
- Update the code so you can read the file size correctly `document.getElementById("cv").files[0]` (this is caused by the previous change).

Demo (also available on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6k4rkja/)):

```js
$("#qual").submit( function(submitEvent) {
    var fileSize = document.getElementById("cv").files[0];
    var sizeInMb = (fileSize.size/1024)/1024;
    var sizeLimit= 2;
    if (sizeInMb > sizeLimit) {
        alert('File size must be less than 2MB');
        // no need for the else part. You want to prevent the submission in this part
        submitEvent.preventDefault();
    }
    
    var filename = $("#cv").val();
    var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
    if (extension == filename) {
        extension = '';
    } else {
        extension = extension.toLowerCase();
    }
    switch (extension) {
        case 'pdf':
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx':
        case 'ppt':
        case 'pptx':
        case 'rtf':
        case 'txt':
            // As the code was changed to the obsubmit, I think you don't need this part
            break;
            
        default:
            alert('Inavlid file type')
            submitEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="qual" class="form-horizontal" action="updater.php"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="act">Upload CV</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input required type="file" name="cv" id="cv" class="btn btn-default"/>
            <span class="help-block">File size must be less than 2MB. <br/>Allowed file types are pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, rtf, txt</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="btn2" name="btn2" class="btn btn-success">Update CV</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

After reading the comments, I reviewed the code and found two possible issues:

1. The submit event was prevented if the file size was correct, but not when the file size failed. Removed the `else` part and added the `preventDefault()` to the `if`.
2. As the code was moved to the form submit instead of the file change, you don't need to mess with the form submit if the extension is right. (Although I'm not 100% positive that this affected the final result). So you could remove the code if the file extension was correct.

I updated the code accordingly and you can see the changes also on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6k4rkja/1/).

Comment: yes. it worked. But i have to click on the 'update cv' button for 2 times

Comment: What do you mean by that? You have to click twice for the form to submit? Could you send a step-by-step list to reproduce the error with the code above?

Comment: yes. I selected a file by clicking 'choose file'. After that when i click 'update cv' nothing happens. Again if i the button, it submits. I think for the first click it checks for file extension and size and allow to submit (but not submit). On second click it submits

Comment: Ok, I think I found a issue that could be causing this. I will update the code

Comment: Check this JSFiddle with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/c6k4rkja/1/. It is working fine for me now.

Comment: yes. i corrected that mistake by myself. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did from a Grails application.  Added a validateSize function:

```
<g:javascript>
    function validateSize() {
        var fileSize = document.getElementById("uploadFile").files[0];
        var sizeInMb = (fileSize.size / 1024) / 1024;
        var sizeLimit = 10;
        if (sizeInMb > sizeLimit) {
            alert('File size must be less than 10 MB');
            return false;
        }
        showSpinner();
        return true;
    }
</g:javascript>
```

Then I used onclick on the input submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="I Accept" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return validateSize()"/>
```